# error in inserting the values in table using phpmyadmin in wamp 2.2

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

Error
SQL query:  Edit

```
INSERT INTO `homedb`.`flights` (`name`, `date`, `time`,`cost` )
       VALUES ( CHAR( 'PIA' ) , 
                CURRENT_DATE( '2014-08-16' ) , 
                CURRENT_TIME( '12:10:00' ) , 
                '500'
)
```

[Table Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LUaR.png)

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
        check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
        the right syntax to use near ''2014-08-16'), CURRENT_TIME('12:10:00'), '500')' 
       at line 1
```

what should be the reason behind this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CURRENT_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) and [`CURRENT_TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) do not expect a parameter to be passed in. They simply return the current date and time from the MySQL server.

Remove the date and time values from your query, or remove CURRENT_DATE() and CURRENT_TIME() function wrappers (leaving the date and time string values).

```
![INSERT INTO `homedb`.`flights` (

`name` ,
`date` ,
`time` ,
`cost` 
)
VALUES (
CHAR( 'PIA' ) , CURRENT_DATE() , CURRENT_TIME() , '500'
)][3]
```

Comment: what if i use TIME only instead of CURRENT_TIME() ?

Comment: it also giving error by keeping  CURRENT_DATE() , CURRENT_TIME() , '500'

Comment: is it the same error when you use just `CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME()` ?